# Unable to resolve the request "Customerlifecycle/Customerlifecycleanalytic"

Tags: php, yii

Its give me this error

> Unable to resolve the request
>   "Customerlifecycle/Customerlifecycleanalytic".

Here is my code:
`Costomerlifecycle Controller`

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap = array('jquery.js' => false, 'jquery-ui.min.js' => false, 'jquery-ui.css' => false);

class Customerlifecycle extends Controller {
    public $layout = '//layouts/column2';

    public function actionCustomerlifecycleanalytic() {
    }
}
```

index.php

```
<li class="">
<a class="subpageaccess" href="<?php echo CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('Customerlifecycle/Customerlifecycleanalytic')); ?>">
Customer Life Cycle Analytics</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

try with first character lowercase.
Because the name of the controller and of the action in url is lowercase. this is the yii convention..

```
<li class="">
   <a class="subpageaccess" href="<?php echo 
   CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('customerlifecycle/customerlifecycleanalytic')); ?>">
    Customer Life Cycle Analytics</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Because the name of the controller and of the action in url is lowercase. this is the yii convention..

Comment: Please don't post the explanation as a comment, rather edit your answer and add it there. It increases the quality of the answer!